# What should I do for this error: require('connect').json() is undefined

Tags: json, node.js, npm, connect

When I typed `gulp test`, I get this error: `require('connect').json() is undefined.`. What should I do?

The detail error message as following:

```
 tianjiedeMacBook-Pro:meiyanapp tianjie$ gulp test
 /Users/tianjie/meiyanruhua/meiyanapp/node_modules/karma/lib/middleware/runner.js:11
 var json = require('connect').json();
                               ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function
     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tianjie/meiyanruhua/meiyanapp/node_modules/karma/lib/middleware/runner.js:11:31)
     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
     at require (module.js:384:17)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tianjie/meiyanruhua/meiyanapp/node_modules/karma/lib/web-server.js:7:24)
     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed that problem by:

`npm install karma karma-jasmine karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev`

Comment: Your solution worked fine. Can you explain me what this command does and what was missed earlier before installing these dependencies?

Comment: This command installs the test packages. What missed earlier I'm not sure, I think it's caused by some dependencies were not installed. And reinstall by this command will automatically search the lost things and install them.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno how that solve the problem ... Actually you are trying to use JSON() in connect module... Error shows json itself undefined and you are invoking using function ()... ?